# how to read a row*col matrix from a file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file-io, matrix

I have the following data in a file .

```
1 3 5 
2 6 8
10 12 14
16 18 20
```

I want to read it in a matrix by 4*3 dimension . Currently I am reading this matrix by the following code assuming the data is stored in the file named "A.txt".

```
A=textread('A.txt');
```

But the problem of this code is that if the file has any space at the last , MATLAB takes that input as zero . For example , if the file "A.txt" has a space after the data , by this piece of code , MATLAB takes input as the following :

```
1 3 5 
2 6 8
10 12 14
16 18 20 0
```

So I want to read the matrix as a row* col syntax . Can you please help me ?

Comment: See if `importdata` works for you - `A=importdata('A.txt')`

Comment: I want to use syntax that can read data from file by specified row and col dimension .

Comment: So I have heard. Did you try the `importdata` approach?

Comment: try `load A.txt -ascii`

Answer (score 1):

An option maybe is to capture the empty spaces as NaNs and after read the file remove the NaNs:

> > A = textread('A.txt','','emptyvalue',NaN)

A =

```
 1     3     5   NaN
 2     6     8   NaN
10    12    14   NaN
16    18    20   NaN
```

> > A = A(:,any(~isnan(A)))

A =

```
 1     3     5
 2     6     8
10    12    14
16    18    20
```